# MYSQL UNION and/or PIVOT

Tags: mysql, union

I have come up with this query which returns the data I need - I was advised to use a UNION and possibly a PIVOT but with limited SQL skills this is what I have come up with.. I did try a PIVOT but got the same result

```
SELECT RoundNo, Team, WL
FROM `MatchDetails2017` 
WHERE Season = 2017 AND Team = 'Team A'
UNION
SELECT RoundNo, Team, WL
FROM `MatchDetails2017` 
WHERE Season = 2017 AND Team = 'Team B'
```

The data is coming out like this

```
RoundNo | Team  |WL  
R1 | Team A | W
R2 | Team A | L
R3 | Team A | W
R4 | Team A | W
R1 | Team B | L
R2 | Team B | W
R3 | Team B | L
R4 | Team B | L
```

But I would like to have the out put like this

```
RoundNo | Team A  | Team B  
R1 | W | L
R2 | L | W
R3 | W | L
R4 | W | L
```

I've updated the query as suggested but its not quite what I am after it's displaying as

```
RoundNo | Team | Team A  | Team B  
R1 | Team A | W | 0
R1 | Team B | 0 | L
R2 | Team A | L | 0
R2 | Team B | 0 | W
R3 | Team A | W | 0
R3 | Team B | 0 | L
R4 | Team A | W | 0
R4 | Team B | 0 | L
```

Comment: best spelling of MySQL ever.

Answer (score 0):

I got it - I just removed Team from the opening SELECT and the GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Season, RoundNo, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Team = 'Team A' THEN WL ELSE 0 END) as Team_A,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Team = 'Team B' THEN WL ELSE 0 END) as Team_B
FROM `MatchDetails2017` 
WHERE Season = 2017
GROUP BY RoundNo
```